# Inexplicable map behavior

Tags: java

I am trying to build a program for a school assignment that generates transitive closures given a set o Functional Dependencies. I am using JAVA . To make it recognize string subsets i have had to build a Class called `Attribute` consisting of a char and a boolean field (to help further recognition of strings containing character sequences

Then i have a class called FunctionalDependency which simply has two maps of
    `<Integer, Attribute>`.
 the first map represents the left hand and the second the right hand of an attribute.

Finally my main program that does the actual calculationhas a map of `Integer,FunctionalDependency`, which represents the set of dependencies that the user wants to input. My problem is located in the method `insertFD()` and more specifically in the first `for{}` block. Whilst in the for block the map seems to have the values i want , outside it (meaning after the last call of the loop) it copies to all the positions of the map the last character of the input destroying the further calculations.

```
   /*The method for inserting a new FD*/
   public void insertFD() throws IOException{
       Map<Integer, Attribute > tempMapLeft= new HashMap<Integer,Attribute>();
       Map<Integer, Attribute > tempMapRight= new HashMap<Integer,Attribute>();
       Attribute tempAttrLeft = new Attribute();
       Attribute tempAttrRight = new Attribute();
       FunctionalDependency tempDependency=new FunctionalDependency();


       String tempString;
       BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       System.out.println("Please give the string for the left hand:");
       System.out.flush();
       tempString=stdin.readLine();
       tempString.toUpperCase();
       System.out.println("Your input is "+tempString);


       for(int j=0;j<tempString.length();j++)
       {
           System.out.println("for j="+j+"letter is "+(tempString.toCharArray()[j]));
           tempAttrLeft.setTheCharacter(tempString.toCharArray()[j]);
           tempAttrLeft.setCheck(true);
           tempMapLeft.put(j, tempAttrLeft);
           System.out.println("I just inserted "+ tempAttrLeft.getTheCharacter());
           System.out.println("Here is the proof: "+tempMapLeft.get(j).getTheCharacter());
       }
       System.out.println(tempMapLeft.get(0).getTheCharacter());
       System.out.println(tempMapLeft.get(1).getTheCharacter());
       tempDependency.setLeftHand(tempMapLeft);
       //fSet.put(number, tempDependency);
       //fSet.get(number).setLeftHand(tempMapLeft);

       System.out.flush();
       System.out.println("Your left hand is at 0 "+  tempDependency.getLeftHand().get(0).getTheCharacter());
       System.out.println("Your left hand is at 1 "+ tempDependency.getLeftHand().get(1).getTheCharacter());
```

I am not any java expert but i cannot see the mistake in my code, i would be glad if you could help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll get more effective help if you don't just dump your entire mass of code on us, but rather take the time to only present the **relevant** code.  In other words, go through your code and boil it down to the *smallest* example that demonstrates the problem.  See http://sscce.org.

Comment: An unrelated tip:  you can omit the `System.out.flush()` calls; `println` flushes the stream automatically unless you have gone out of your way to cause it not to.

Comment: thanks! editing the question now!

Comment: You say it has the values inside the for block but not outside it. Which particular for block?

Comment: The first one of the insertFD() method, i just edited the code to show it clearly, i only have the problematic piece of code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you keep re-using the same tempAttrLeft and tempAttrRight in each pass of the loop.  Every key in the map is pointing to the same object!  You need to create a new tempAttrLeft and tempAttrRight on each pass of the loop.  The map keeps a reference to the object you put in it, it doesn't "copy" it.  So when  you change the values on the next pass of the loop, that map key is pointed to the same one with the new values.

Comment: Thank you ! I made the declaration of the `tempAttribute` in the `for` loop instead of outside it and the problem was fixed! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the expected and actual output. But few things you can try :

1. You will not get the uppercase in `tempString.toUpperCase();` This is because of immutability feature of `String`. Instead do : `tempString = tempString.toUpperCase();`
2. Re-initialize the `tempString` when accepting input for right hand.

Comment: Thanks RC for editing my post :-). I will take care next time.

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop, you are using an `Attribute` instance which is the **same** for every `j`, so after the loop, every map entry contains the same `Attribute`

Comment: Thanks! That was the exact problem, now its fixed!